# How to make multiple selection in Contact Form 7 with images?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to do the same as here:

```
http://deinehelfer24.de/renovierungen/
```

As I understand it, this is done on contact form 7, but how are the images and multiple selections implemented?

Comment: See https://contactform7.com/editing-form-template/. There are buttons to generate tags.

Comment: First row, custom styled radio buttons, second row custom styled chechboxes, toggling second line bit a JS, good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

I feel generous today, simpe example ho you can style labels

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Beneris/65mdtpo3/28/
```

HTML

```
<form>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1-1" value="1">
      <label for="group1-1">
        <figure><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"><h3>Radio 1</h3></figure>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1-2" value="2">
      <label for="group1-2">
        <figure><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"><h3>Radio 2</h3></figure>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1-3" value="3">
      <label for="group1-3">
        <figure><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"><h3>Radio 3</h3></figure>
      </label>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-wrap to-toggle 1 3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="group2" id="group2-1" value="1">
      <label for="group2-1">
        <figure><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"><h3>checkbox 1</h3></figure>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap to-toggle 1 2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="group2" id="group2-2" value="2">
      <label for="group2-2">
        <figure><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"><h3>checkbox 2</h3></figure>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap to-toggle 1 2 3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="group2" id="group2-3" value="3">
      <label for="group2-3">
        <figure><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"><h3>checkbox 3</h3></figure>
      </label>
    </div> 
  </div>

</form>
```

CSS

```
.radio-group {
  display:block;
}

.input-group .input-wrap{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
}

label figure {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

figure h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.input-group input:checked ~ label figure {
  background-color: red;
}

.input-wrap input {
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$('.to-toggle').hide();
$('input[name=group1]').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
  $('.to-toggle').hide();
  $('.to-toggle input').prop('checked', false);
  $('.to-toggle.' + val).show();
  //alert(val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to integrate it with contact-form-7?

Comment: Contact form 7 works fine wit plain html inputs inserted, just not recognizes fields when editing "Mail body", but you can easily add `[group1]` and `[group2]` to mail body template and values will be passed trough.